# Определите количество "почти счастливых" билетов

Tags: математика, комбинаторика

Номер билета из n цифр, где n чѐтное, называется ―"почти счастливым", если в нем
сумма первых n/2 цифр ровно на единицу отличается от суммы остальных цифр.
Например, 123005 или 123700. Номер может начинаться с любого числа нулей.
Определите количество ―"почти счастливых билетов" для следующих значений n:

1) n = 6

2) n = 10

3) n = 20

4) n = 100

Опишите, как именно вы получили соответствующие значения.

Мои догадки:

Значит я разобрался и вот что максимум понял это то,что например,если число 6-ти значное , то мы берем 6/2 и получаем 3, потом сумму трех первых цифр складываем и складываем сумму оставшихся цифр, и сравниваем эти две суммы, нужно чтобы между ними была разница в единицу и если такая присутствует,то этот билет "почти счастливый".

Comment: Надо подсчитать сколько трехзначных чисел с суммой 1,2, до 27.

Comment: @becouse УМОЛЯЮ Вас решите

Comment: Первая половина НИКАК не зависит от второй половины.

Comment: @Akina можете написать решение

Comment: @Akina дали решение, посмотрите правильно или нет

Comment: @becouse дали решение, посмотрите правильно или нет

Answer (score 2):

Ну, аналитическую формулу не выведу, но посчитать можно...

Рассмотрим D(k,l) - число k-значных чисел (с ведущими нулями в том числе) с суммой цифр l.

А теперь посмотрим общее число почти счастливых билетов (для k=n/2)...

Для суммы слева 0 справа годится D(k,1) чисел - итого D(k,0)*D(k,1)
Для суммы слева 1 справа годится D(k,0)+D(k,2) чисел - итого D(k,1)*D(k,0)+D(k,1)*D(k,2)
Для суммы слева 2 справа годится D(k,1)+D(k,3) чисел - итого D(k,2)*D(k,1)+D(k,2)*D(k,3)
...
Для суммы слева 9k справа годится D(k,9k-1) чисел - итого D(k,9k)*D(k,9k-1)

Суммируя, получаем общее количество как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь как считать D(k,l) - простое динамическое программирование:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

из того соображения, что к числу с k-1 цифрой приписываем цифры от 0 до 9. Начальные условия для D(0,l) очевидны - при l==0 получаем 1, для остальных - 0.

Собственно, все. Пишем программу. Мемоизацию (или ДП снизу вверх) дописывайте сами :)

```
long long int D(int k, int l)
{
    if (k==0) return (l==0);
    long long int sum = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<=9; ++j) sum += D(k-1,l-j);
    return sum;
}

long long int res(int k)
{
    long long int sum = 0;
    for(int l = 1; l <= 9*k; ++l)
        sum += D(k,l)*D(k,l-1);
    return 2*sum;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(int n = 2; n <= 12; n+=2)
        cout << setw(2) << n << ":  " << res(n/2) << endl;
}
```

Результаты для небольших n:

```
 2:  18
 4:  1320
 6:  109494
 8:  9564720
10:  860000900
12:  78783456336
14:  7312306950130
```

Для очень больших n нужна длинная арифметика...

P.S. Не выдержал - переписал... См. [тут](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GtudyjbrGyTvOxAx).

Для n==100 - 277195334834500944669228740375357778944913131715952295846893641728073727377808583283711688841134000 почти счастливых билетов...

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из *Номер может начинаться с любого числа нулей* к примеру `000001,001000` и так далее можно прийти к тому что числа растут `000001,001000,002001,002003,003002,003004,004003,004005,005004,005006...055054,055056,056055,056057...999998` разница между всеми этими числами
`999,1001,2,999,2,999,2,999,2...` и так будет далее возьмём максимальное значение `999998 9+9+9=27`
соответственно тут уже закономерность и прогрессия которую ты учил в 9 классе.
Считай An (для каждого отдельно) то есть для `q=2` и для `q=999` и потом их сплюсуй а `n=6` `n=10` ты получишь исходя из результата `An1` + `An2` (не имееться ввиду `000001` как `An1` и `001000` как `An2`) к примеру получиться `n` "почти счастливых" билетов это n*на 1,8 получишь количество счастливых билетов для `n=10` так же потом делаешь и для `n=50` и `n=100`  ты есть если бы было **к примеру** `n=1000` ("счастливых билетов") `*1,8 = 1800` для `n=10` и `90000` для `n = 50` соответственно `90000*2=180000` для `n=100`
На число `1001` не обращай внимание оно `1` раз только получилось

То есть у тебя есть:

```
d1=2  
d2=999
A(max)=999998  
A(min)=000001  
A(a)-?
```

Про `q` могу ошибиться это может `d` я уже не помню как там это подписуется q наверное геомертическая а d алгебраическая прогрессия но дело не в этом оно тебе особо не поможет тебе больше помогут формулы скорее всего это алгебраическая закономерность я бы считал по формуле `A(n)`
Сори за выделения просто сайт думал что это код
Я не гарантирую что это 100% правильное решение но я бы решал так

Comment: хорошо,спасибо конечно) напишите ниже в двух словах как считать для n=6,10,20,100

Comment: См. Задачу о счастливых троллейбусных билетах. Кодичество чисел с заданной суммой это число сочетаний. Так что решение не верное.

Comment: Вот решение задачи о счастливых билетах. Решение легко адаптировать под вашу задачу.
https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D1.88.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.81_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.89.D1.8C.D1.8E_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D1.83.D0.BB.D1.8B_.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.BB.D1.8E.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F-.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.BB.D1.8E.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F

Comment: becouse,спасибо, на самом деле интересная задача долго думал как решить, но видимо сейчас своим умом мало таких задач сделаешь.  
Под *своим умом* я имею ввиду без подсказок из интернета